# To evaluate the limit as h approaches 0, how do I rewrite the limit in terms of theta?

Tags: calculus, limits

I found a [Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3ttw.png) from the textbook which is not well explained...or not at all explained. And it would be interesting to know how to solve it. Or perhaps I am simply that bad at understanding squeeze theorem.

3. If you want to evaluate $\lim _ { h \rightarrow 0 } \frac { \sin 5 h } { 3 h } ,$ it is a good idea to rewrite the
   limit in terms of the variable (choose one):

$\begin{array} { l l l } { \text { (a) } \theta = 5 h } & { \text { (b) } \theta = 3 h } & { \text { (c) } \theta = \frac { 5 h } { 3 } } \end{array}$

Basically: for the limit as h approaches $0$, in the equation: $\sin(5h/3h)$, how should you rewrite the limit in terms of the variable theta?

For clarity's sake, I don't care much for the answer itself. It's a "completion" grade anyway. I am, however, interested in what logic goes into determining how you rewrite the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic behind is that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}= 1$ is known.

So, one would like to transform the expression to contain this limit which excludes the "problem with the sine".

Hence, $\theta = 5h$ would be a good choice.

Now, you will see how this transforms the limit in a nice way:

$$\frac{\sin 5h}{3h} = \frac{\sin \theta}{3\frac{\theta}{5}}= \frac{5}{3}\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}\stackrel{\theta to 0}{\longrightarrow}\frac{5}{3}$$

Comment: Thank you for the expanded explanation at the bottom. It roughly followed my intuition from reading David's answer, but having it splayed out like that makes it all make much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You probably know
$$\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}=1\ .$$
If you have sine of a multiple of $\theta$, for example as in your problem
$$\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\sin5\theta}{3\theta}\ ,$$
this makes it a bit harder.  On the other hand if you have a multiple of $\theta$ in the denominator, it scarcely makes it harder at all because you can factor out the constant, e.g.,
$$\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\sin\theta}{7\theta}=\frac17\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}\ .$$
So taking $\theta=5h$ would be the way to go IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first observe that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac {\sin x } {x} = 1$.

To show the above limiting value let us first try to give a bound for $\frac {\sin x} {x}$. Note that, $\sin x < x < \tan x$ for all $x \in (0,\frac {\pi} {2})$. Also for all $x \in (0,\frac {\pi} {2})$ we have $\sin x,\tan x > 0$. So we get from the above inequality that $$1 < \frac {x} {\sin x} <\sec x\ \text{for all}\ x \in \left (0, \frac {\pi} {2}\right).$$ or in other words

$$\cos x < \frac {\sin x} {x} <1\ \text{for all}\ x \in \left (0, \frac {\pi} {2}\right).$$

Now $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \cos x =1$ and $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^+} 1 = 1$. So by Squeeze theorem we get $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\sin x} {x} =1$.

To prove that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^{-}} \frac {\sin x} {x} = 1$ use the inequality

$$\tan x < x < \sin x,\ \text {for all}\ x \in \left (-\frac{\pi} {2},0 \right ).$$

Now to evaluate $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {\sin 5h} {3h}$ first observe that for $h \neq 0$ $\frac {\sin 5h} {3h} = \frac {5} {3} \frac {\sin 5h} {5h}$. So

$$\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {\sin 5h} {3h} = \frac {5} {3}\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {\sin 5h} {5h} =\frac 5 3.$$ (Here you should observe that as $h \rightarrow 0,$ $5h \rightarrow 0$. So 
$\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {\sin 5h} {5h} = \lim\limits_{5h \rightarrow 0} \frac {\sin 5h} {5h} = 1$).